Setting up direct connection over Ethernet cable with netplan between two Ubuntu PCs
I have two computers running Ubuntu 22.04. I have connected them with a patch cable and want to SSH from one computer (let's call it the client) to the other (let's call it the server).
The server is running netplan, its configuration file is:
$ netplan get
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: NetworkManager
  ethernets:
    id0:
      match:
        name: "enx000ec6954183"
      addresses:
      - "192.168.1.102/24"
      dhcp4: false

On the client, I have added a new connection profile with the Network Settings GUI and set the IPv4 tab to "Shared to other computers" (IP: 10.42.0.1).
What is required to finish the set up so I can ping the server from the client?


On the client, I have added a new connection profile with the Network Settings GUI and set the IPv4 tab to "Shared to other computers" (IP: 10.42.0.1).

Do not set the IPv4 tab to "Shared to other computers". Set the profile to "Manual" and configure an IP address that matches the subnet of the server's address (i.e. in your case 192.168.1.x with netmask 255.255.255.0 to match the 192.168.1.102/24).
If you use the "Shared to other computers" option, then it decides what IP address the interface will use, and therefore decides what IP addresses other computers on that connection will use – meaning that the server would need to have an IP address configured following the client's choice (preferably using DHCP). This would technically work, but is a bit backwards, and generally not what you want.
"Shared to other computers" is what some systems would call "Hotspot" mode – it's for use on systems that receive Internet access through interface A and want to provide that through interface B (e.g. you connect to some public Wi-Fi using a typical "Automatic" profile and then redistribute it using "Shared to other computers" on the Ethernet profile). It can still function even without Internet access, i.e. would still provide local DHCP service for other machines, but even in that case it would be more appropriate to run it on a server, not on a client.
